# Composition of linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm an engineer trying to brush up on basic linear algebra, so please excuse me if this question is too basic. I'm having difficulty with the following task:

> A linear transformation $L:R^2 \to R^2$ meets the following conditions: $L(1,2)=(2,4) ; L(1,3)=(-1,-3).$ Find $L^{100}(0,1)$

I've found a theorem that I think might come in handy, but in order to make use of it I have to find eigenvalues and a proper transition matrix (where the eigenvectors are the basis). Eigenvalues aren't a problem, but how can I find the aforementioned change of basis matrix not knowing the basis of L? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As $L(1,2) = (2,4) = \underbrace 2_{\uparrow}(1,2)$, that $2$ is one of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

As $L(1,2) = (2,4) = \underbrace 2_{\uparrow}(1,2)$, that $2$ is one of the eigenvalues with $(1,2)$ as a corresponding eigenvector. Similarly from $L(1,3) = (-1,-3)$.

For some $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ that represent the linear transformation $L$,

$$M\pmatrix{1\\2} = 2\pmatrix{1\\2};\quad M\pmatrix{1\\3} = -1\pmatrix{1\\3}$$

Placing these two column vectors side by side,

$$\begin{align*}
M\pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}  &= \pmatrix{2 & -1\\4&-3}\\
&=\pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}\pmatrix{2&0\\0&-1}\\
M &= \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}\pmatrix{2&0\\0&-1} \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}^{-1}\\
M^{100} &= \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}\pmatrix{2&0\\0&-1}^{100} \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}^{-1}\\
&= \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}\pmatrix{2^{100}&0\\0&(-1)^{100}} \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}^{-1}
\end{align*}$$